# How to permit an array json with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parameters, parameter-passing, strong-parameters

For json

```
{
   "version":"1",
   "configs":[
      {
         "title":"Good",
         "body":"Body"
      },
      {
         "title":"Good",
         "body":"Body"
      }
   ]
}
```

How to permit it with Rails' `params.permit` in controller?

I tried

```
  params.permit(
    config_setting: [
      :version,
      configs: [
        :title,
        :body,
      ]
    ],
  )
```

But seems not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are permitting a json with the following structure:

```json
{
   "config_setting": [
      {
         "version":"1",
         "configs":[
            {
               "title":"Good",
               "body":"Body"
            },
            {
               "title":"Good",
               "body":"Body"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Just add `config_setting` node to the data or adjust your strong params block to:

```rb
params.permit(
   :version,
   configs: [
     :title,
     :body,
   ] 
)
```

Comment: Actually, it is an array of `config_setting`